# reloading a web page and placing page at same place where user was at

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Is there a way in react or javascript to after reloading a page make that page to be at the same place where the user was looking at? So far, location.reload reloads the page but places that page at its beginning.

Answer (score 0):

Add additional true parameter to force reload.

```
document.location.reload(true)
```

`document.location.reload()` stores the position,

> ordinary reload tries to restore the scroll position after reloading the page, while in forced mode (when parameter is set to true) the new DOM gets loaded with scrollTop == 0.

Reference  : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Location/reload

Comment: My web page is defined by react components and the html page has only <div> with an id tag. It seems this method does not work under these circumstances.

Answer (score 0):

You can add a `scroll` listener, and on scroll, save the current position scrolled in `sessionStorage`. Then, on pageload, check to see if the `sessionStorage` item is populated, and if it is, set the current scroll position to the number saved in `sessionStorage`:

```
if (sessionStorage.scroll) document.documentElement.scrollTop = sessionStorage.scroll;

window.addEventListener('scroll', () => {
  sessionStorage.scroll = document.documentElement.scrollTop;
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/1rg37zfd/

(Cannot embed into stack snippet because it doesn't support `sessionStorage`)

Comment: Does this work? I thought the API was `setItem` and `getItem`

Comment: Dot notation works just fine and is more terse, so I prefer it. Check the fiddle - it works

Comment: Cool, I guess it works bc I'm getting access denied for jsfiddle

Answer (score 0):

You can use localStorage to set a value.  then in your init() check for where the user was last seen. The nextBtn, in the function for that, that is where we increment the page number and save it.  i usually use a very minimized sync function to handle any refreshing i may want to do.

HTML:

```
<div id='myPage'></div>
```

JavaScript:

```
(function () {
    "use strict";
var myUI, userData, myPages;

myPages = [
    "Home","Page 2","Page 3","Page 4","Page 5"//when the user's page number is summoned with this object, pages will reflect when the syncFunc is ran
];

userData = 0;//out item where we save the users page number

myUI = {
    init: () => {
        var uData = localStorage.getItem("userData");//we look to see what is the value

        if (!uData || uData === null) {
            localStorage.setItem("userData", 0);//this only sets the user's page to 0 on first load or if anything goes wrong
        }

        var pageHolder = document.createElement("h3"),
            nextBtn =  document.createElement("button");

        nextBtn.innerHTML = " > ";
        nextBtn.onclick = myUI.nextPage(userData, pageHolder);

        pageHolder.innerHTML = myPages[uData];

        myPage.appendChild(pageHolder);

        myPage.appendChild(nextBtn);

        myUI.syncPage(uData, pageHolder, nextBtn);
    },
    syncPage: (uData, pageHolder) => {//i mean, you could do a whole window reload and it still work, but why do that when you can just sync things on the fly

        pageHolder.innerHTML = myPages[uData];
        //alert(uData);
    },
    nextPage: (userData, pageHolder) => {
        return () => {  

            var uData = localStorage.getItem("userData"),//checking for the data when the user hits a button.
                newPage;
            if (uData >= 4) { newPage = +uData - 4 } else { newPage = +uData + 1; }//iterate by 1 unless we reach our limit

            localStorage.setItem("userData", newPage);//save it

            uData = localStorage.getItem("userData");//force our script to recognize the newly saved value
            setTimeout(() => {//timeout for dramatic effect if desired 
            myUI.syncPage(uData, pageHolder);//run a function to sync

            }, 100);

        }
    }

};
    window.onload = () => {
        myUI.init();//initialize
    };
})();
```